# Navigation drawer inside v-card not working in Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Im trying to add navigation panel to `v-card` but somehow when adding the navigation drawer, everything that is in the v-card is being pushed down- out of the card.

```
 <v-card flat outlined>
   
      <v-navigation-drawer v-model="drawer"
      :mini-variant.sync="mini"
      permanent>
      <v-row>
       <v-btn class="float-right" icon @click.stop="mini = !mini">
                <v-icon color="black">mdi-chevron-left</v-icon>
              </v-btn>
      </v-row>
      <p>
          
        <v-card v-if="!mini">
        TEST
     </v-card></p>
    </v-navigation-drawer>

        <v-row  dense>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <PlotCard
              style="min-height: 350px"
              :value="1837.32"
              :percentage="3.2"
              :loading="isLoading1"
              percentage-label="vs last week"
              action-label="V2"
            ></PlotCard>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>



        <v-row  dense>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <table-card class="h-full" label="Recent Orders" />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>

    </v-card>
```

I've recreated the problem here https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-lxq25?file=/src/components/ExampleComponent.vue:38-55

As you can see navigation drawer is in the v-card but other cards are being pushed outside.
Ultimately I want to use the `right` attribute of navigation drawer in Vuetify to have in on the right but even normal one ins not working. Any idea why this might be happening?

EDIT: Adding absolute makes the navigation-drawer appear as overlay, but I was trying to make it appear form the right and "squeeze" the content of the card to the left.

Comment: Not sure if I am misunderstanding, but putting `absolute` will keep the cards in place: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-558ec

Comment: @AJT82 hmm it kind of works, but is it possible to use absolute but still get the drawer to push the  other compoents the left (squeeze them) when it pops open? Instead of overlaying them like it works in your example.

Comment: You can simply add `d-flex` class to `v-card`

Comment: @IVOGELOV wont work simply like that

Comment: you have to create a layout, means the content should go to v-main, then your navigation-drawer can have "app" and "right" props to make it part of layout.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-qjjnp?file=/src/components/ExampleComponent.vue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

vuetify have a layout system. for now you have content and navigation drawer, and the navigation drawer dont act right because it doesnt know where it belongs. you have to push your content to v-main(vuetify content layout component) and by passing `app` prop to navigation drawer you tell its part of layout and it is sidebar. more info:
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#default-application-markup .
and pass `right` to push navigation to right. demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-playground-forked-qjjnp?file=/src/components/ExampleComponent.vue

Comment: I noticed that using `app` prop in the navigation drawe pushes it to the main app layout. But what I acutally tried to do was to have the drawer inside the card. I have already another app-bar (horizontal) that is used as main navigation for the app, and i only need the drawer in the `v-card`